# SQL update not working with integer ID

Tags: java, database, h2

This command on SQL Server

```
UPDATE tbl SET name='Hi' WHERE id=''
```

works if 'id' is set as an integer value, but it does not work on H2.

What may be the solution?

Comment: please provide details of ur table schema

Comment: How are you doing the SQL update through java?

Comment: @Philippe Billerot Please provide more substance to your question. What is the exact error message that you are recieving? Is there an Error code? What DBMS are you using? MySQL server, MS SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: @bakoyaro: H2 **is** a database http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_%28DBMS%29

Comment: @BalusC your 'correction' completely changed the question, I will undo it. Before your correction: `ID=''` (where it's clear why it can't work: an empty string can't be converted to a number); after your correction: `id=?` (this is a parameter, and H2 will not throw an exception).

Answer (score 6):

If ID is integer, you shouldn't use quotes for the value:

```
UPDATE TEST SET NAME='Hi' WHERE ID = 5; // not ID = '5'
```

Many databases will accept the quoted version, but are not required to by the SQL language specification.

Comment: H2 also supports ID = '5' even if ID is a integer... that's not the problem. The problem is that the user used ID = '', which seems to be supported by MySQL and (probably?) Oracle, but not by any other database I tested (PostgreSQL, Derby, HSQLDB).

Comment: I am not satisfied because the request is the result of a generator of SQL commands that do not control the type of data.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`UPDATE TEST SET NAME='Hi' WHERE ID='1';`
that is working in sql server even if id field is integer 
but if you want to update the row where id is null then you have to use below statement :
`UPDATE TEST SET NAME='Hi' WHERE ID is Null;` 
instead of  `UPDATE TEST SET NAME='Hi' WHERE ID ='';`

And if id is varchar then you can use your statement to update the values where ID is not null and data is not available there.
But if you want to update the values for record where  NULL value of ID field then you have to use

`UPDATE TEST SET NAME='Hi' WHERE ID is Null;`

Comment: +1 : Some database consider '' and null to be equivalent (which they shouldn't)

Comment: Hi Mark,may be yes for Some Database system.

Comment: I am not satisfied because the request is the result of a generator of SQL commands that do not control the type of data.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

H2 throws an exception because it can't convert the empty string `''` to a number. H2 internally uses `java.lang.Long.parseLong("")` which fails with `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`.

For the SQL script:

```
drop table tbl;
create table tbl(id int primary key, name varchar(255));
insert into tbl values(1, 'Hello');
UPDATE tbl SET name='Hi' WHERE id='';
```

H2 will throw the exception:

```
Data conversion error converting  [22018-161]
```

Most other databases (PostgreSQL, Apache Derby, HSQLDB) throw a similar exception.

You need to use a number, or `IS NULL` as in:

```
UPDATE tbl SET name='Hi' WHERE id IS NULL;
```

or

```
UPDATE tbl SET name='Hi' WHERE id = 0;
```